# Calling a php SOP webservice from c# that does not support wsdl

Tags: c#, .net, php, web-services

Can any body have idea how to consume php soap web service that have no support wsdl.

I want to add reference in .Net to generate client but failed.

When i saw in browser with ?wsdl it shows message wsdl is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said: you can not. WDSL is there for development environments to know how to deal with a web service. Whoever wrote the web serivce made sure (or was ignorant enough to now know) that it is not usable from any tooling support.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consult the [PHP: SOAP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) and verify that you wrote the PHP webservice correctly.

And you can also look at this example: [PHP Webservice and C# / .NET SOAP Clients](http://sanity-free.org/article25.html)

You need to configure the SOAP Service to support WSDL

> (Web Services Description Language) An
>   XML-based language for describing Web
>   services and how to access them.

Otherwise .NET won't know what or how to use it.